# Cannot handle POST request with this servlet

Tags: javascript, java, html, json, servlets

this is my servlet

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.servlet.Servlet;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

//import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

import com.mysql.jdbc.Statement;
/**
 * Servlet implementation class Login
 */
@WebServlet("/Login")
public class Login extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Connection connection;
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Login() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        ServletContext context = config.getServletContext();
        String url = context.getInitParameter("dbUrl");
        String dbUser = context.getInitParameter("dbUser");
        String dbPassword = context.getInitParameter("dbPassword");
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, dbUser, dbPassword);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void destroy() {
        if (connection != null) {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
            }
        }
    }
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(request, response);

    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("plain/text");

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 
        String usernameV = request.getParameter("usernameV");
        String passwordV = request.getParameter("passwordV");

        json.put("ris", 0);
        try {
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ? AND password = ? ";         
            PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            stmt.setString(1, usernameV);
            stmt.setString(2, passwordV);
            json.put("password", usernameV);
            json.put("username", usernameV);

            out.print(json.toJSONString());
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()) {
                json.replace("ris", 1);
                out.print(json.toJSONString());
                stmt.close();
                rs.close();
                return;
            }
            stmt.close();
            rs.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            json.replace("err", e.getMessage());
            out.print(json.toJSONString());

        }


        out.print(json.toJSONString());``
    }

    }
```

and here's my javascript

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(window).keydown(function(event){//impedisco l'invio del form premendo invio
  if(event.keyCode == 13) {
   event.preventDefault();
   return false;
  }
 });
 
 $("#bottone").click(function(){
  $("#risultato").attr("style", "color: black;");
  $("#risultato").html("Caricamento..."); 
  var username = $("#username").val();
  var password = $("#password").val();
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "Register",
   //data: {"username" : username, "password": password},
   data: "username=" + username + "&password=" + password,
   dataType: "text",
   success: function(msg)
   {    
    var result = $.parseJSON(msg);    
    if(result.error){
     switch (result.error) {
     case 1:
      Step();
            
      break;
     default:
      $("#risultato").html(msg);
     break;
     }
    }else{
     $("#bottone").prop('disabled', true);
     $("#risultato").attr("style", "color: black;");
     $("#risultato").html("Benvenuto " + username + "!");
    }             
   },
   error: function()
   {
    $("#risultato").attr("style", "color: red;");
    $("#risultato").html("Errore di connessione!");
   }
  });
 });
});

function Step() {
 $("#risultato").attr("style", "color: red;");
 $("#risultato").html("Username gi&agrave; esistente!<br>");
 $("#risultato").append("<p>Inserisci la tua password : <input type='password' name='passwordV' id='passwordV'> <input type='button' id='bottone1' value='Login'> </p>");
 
 $("#bottone1").click(function(){
  $("#res").attr("style", "color: black;");
  $("#res").html("Caricamento..."); 
  var username = $("#username").val();
  var password = $("#passwordV").val();
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "Login",
  data: "usernameV=" + username + "&passwordV=" + password,
  dataType: "text",
  success: function(msg)
  {    
   var resulto = $.parseJSON(msg);    
   if(resulto.ris){
    switch (resulto.ris) {
    case 1:
     $("#res").attr("style", "color: red;");
     $("#res").html("Benvenuto " + username + "!");
           
     break;
    default:
     $("#res").html(msg);
    break;
    }
   }else{
    $("#bottone1").prop('disabled', true);
    $("#res").attr("style", "color: black;");
    $("#res").html("password errata:"+ password);
    $("#stack").attr("style", "color: black;");
    $("#stack").html(msg);
   }             
  },
  error: function()
  {
   $("#res").attr("style", "color: red;");
   $("#res").html("Errore di connessione!");
  }
 });
 });
}
```

if it helps, i post also the default.jsp page:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Chat Room</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <form name="modulo" action="">
        <p>
            Nome utente: <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
            Password:    <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
            <input type="button" id="bottone" value="Registrati!">
        </p>
    </form>
    <div id="risultato"></div>
    <div id ="res"></div>
    <div id="stack"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

i add also the Register.java servlet.. This one does work, and, as you  can see, it is almost the same as the login one.

```
package it.marco.chat.servlets;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.servlet.Servlet;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

//import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

import com.mysql.jdbc.Statement;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Register
 */
@WebServlet("/Register")
public class Register extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Connection connection;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Register() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * @see Servlet#init(ServletConfig)
     */
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        ServletContext context = config.getServletContext();
        String url = context.getInitParameter("dbUrl");
        String dbUser = context.getInitParameter("dbUser");
        String dbPassword = context.getInitParameter("dbPassword");
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, dbUser, dbPassword);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @see Servlet#destroy()
     */
    public void destroy() {
        if (connection != null) {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("plain/text");

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        json.put("error", 0);


        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");


        try {
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?";           
            PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            stmt.setString(1, username);
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()) {
                json.replace("error", 1);
                out.print(json.toJSONString());
                stmt.close();
                rs.close();
                return;
            }
            stmt.close();
            rs.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
        }


        int uid = -1;

        try {
            String sql = "INSERT INTO user(username,password) VALUES(?,?)";
            PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
            stmt.setString(1, username);
            stmt.setString(2, password);
            stmt.execute();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.getGeneratedKeys(); 
            if (rs.next()) {
                uid = rs.getInt(1);
            }
            stmt.close();
            rs.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        json.put("uid", uid);

        out.print(json.toJSONString());
    }

}
```

i cannot understand why the servlet is not able to handle the POST request.. I mean, i have already set up one servlet that hanldles the register part and it works perfectly.
I have tried all the evening to make it work, and i am pretty sure there's a stupid mistake i am not able to see, that's why i have come here.
I hope that someone is able to help me.
Thank you

Comment: what is the response you're getting ? if you open in the browser inspect element > network what is the response ?

Comment: it prints "Errore di connessione!", that is the message printed when i have error in $.ajax

Comment: can you post your html please

Comment: i've just done it

Comment: change the error part to `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(jqXHR.status);
    alert(textStatus);
    alert(errorThrown);
}`

instead of 
`   error: function()
   {
    $("#risultato").attr("style", "color: red;");
    $("#risultato").html("Errore di connessione!");
   }`
and tell us the result

Comment: it says the same red sentence "errore di connessione", should i change the error part also in the first part of the script?

Comment: now that i have changed in both of the POST requests, i get this three alerts: 404 , error and empty alert

Comment: your problem is here url: "Register", can you use complete path please i mean use something like /path/idontcare/bingo ythe error 404 is because you're not able to get the real url alos it would be good to know what url is i mean can you print it?

Comment: \workspace\ChatMarco\src\it\marco\chat\servlets this is the path or both servlets. Register does work, login doesn't

Answer (score 0):

change this :

```
@WebServlet("/Login")
```

to

```
@WebServlet(name = "Login", urlPatterns = { "/Login" })
```

it will work believe me

Comment: no it does not work unfortunately, i have just tried. Btw the other servlet that handles the registration part is written almost the same as this one. So i cannot get why the Login.java does not work

Comment: Ok can you make the change i told you, then compile and refresh and restart the server please i really did what you said